# Thymleaf picks mainLayout.html instead of home.html when string "home" is returned from controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot project where ‘/’ will be redirected to ‘/home’ in HomeController bcz of the setting in WebConfig class and from there the return string is “home” so the thymeleaf template engine will look for home.html inside the templates folder but instead of it is looking for mainLayout.html which is inside the layout folder which is inside the template folder.

I have seen some blogs on how to use thymleaf with spring but didn't get the solution.

This is the link for complete project:
https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/jcart

Go to jcart-site then look for WebConfig class then look for HomeController class and then look for templates folder there check mainLayout.html

Comment: Please post the code that's necessary to reproduce the problem within the question itself. That's necessary according to [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and it allows us to properly help you, rather than having to debug your entire application.

Comment: I mentioned the github link for full code.

Comment: As I mentioned, that's too much for us to go through to be able to help. It's your task to come up with just the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your index.html file

```
 <script>
    window.location="/home";
</script>
```

it will redirect to your homecontroller.